# Java regex get exact token value

Tags: java, regex

I've string like below , want to get the value of `cn=ADMIN` , but dont know how to get to using regex efficient way.

> group:192.168.133.205:387/cn=ADMIN,cn=groups,dc=mi,dc=com,dc=usa

Comment: How would you do it inefficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well ... like this?

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "group:192.168.133.205:387/cn=ADMIN,cn=groups,dc=mi,dc=com,dc=usa";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*/(.*)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String right = matcher.group(1);
            String[] parts = right.split(",");
            for (String part : parts) {
                System.err.println("part: " + part);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
part: cn=ADMIN
part: cn=groups
part: dc=mi
part: dc=com
part: dc=usa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String bubba = "group:192.168.133.205:387/cn=ADMIN,cn=groups,dc=mi,dc=com,dc=usa";
   String target = "cn=ADMIN";

   for(String current: bubba.split("[/,]")){
       if(current.equals(target)){
           System.out.println("Got it");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern for regex
`cn=([a-zA-Z0-9]+?),`
Your name will be in group 1 of matcher. You can extend character classes if you allow spaces etc.